# How to change the date spacing in pgfcalendar?

Tags: tikz-pgf, calendar, tikz-calendar

I did not find any option to change the date spacing in pgfcalendar tutorial can somebody suggest me how do i change the spacing between dates. Here is MWE

```
 \documentclass[border=4.9mm, multi={tikzpicture}]{standalone}
 %\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,bmargin=3cm,tmargin=4.5cm,centering,a4paper]{geometry}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{xcolor}

 %%in preamble:
 %
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{positioning,calendar}
 \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

 \newcommand{\calrow}[1]{\node[anchor=base east](Mon){\rotatebox{0}{M}};
 \node[base right=of Mon](Tue){\rotatebox{0}{T}}; \node[base right=of Tue](Wed){W};
 \node[base right=of Wed](Thu){T}; \node[base right=of Thu](Fri){F};
 \node[base right=of Fri](Sat){S}; \node[base right=of Sat](Sun){\color{red}S};
 \node[darkgreen,above=of Wed]{\textbf{#1}};}

 \newcommand{\calperiod}[1]{\calendar[dates=\the\year-#1-01 to \the\year-#1-last]
 if(Sunday) [red] \holidays;}

 \newcommand{\holidays}{% holidays in Italy
 if (equals=01-01) [black!50]%
 if (equals=01-06) [black!50]%
 if (equals=04-04) [black!50]%
 if (equals=04-05) [black!50]%
 if (equals=04-25) [black!50]%
 if (equals=05-01) [black!50]%
 if (equals=05-01) [black!50]%
 if (equals=06-02) [black!50]%
 if (equals=08-15) [black!50]%
 if (equals=11-01) [black!50]%
 if (equals=12-08) [black!50]%
 if (equals=12-25) [black!50]%
 if (equals=12-26) [black!50]%
 }

 \colorlet{darkgreen}{green!50!black}
 \year=2017
 \begin{document}
 %%in document:
 %
 \begin{tikzpicture}[every calendar/.style={week list}]
 \sffamily
 \matrix[%
 row 1/.style={darkgreen,node distance=.3ex},%
 row 3/.style={darkgreen,node distance=.3ex},
 row 5/.style={darkgreen,node distance=.3ex},
 row 7/.style={darkgreen,node distance=.3ex},
 column sep=1ex,%
 draw=darkgreen,thick, rectangle=9.5pt,%
 postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.61 with
 {\node[fill=white,text=blue,font={\bfseries\Large}] (year) {\the\year};}
 }},
 % year on frame: decorations.markings library
 ]{%

 % first row: week day and month
 \calrow{\color{blue}Arkoi} & \calrow{\color{blue}Thangthang} & \calrow{\color{blue}Therepo} \\
 \calperiod{01} & \calperiod{02} & \calperiod{03} \\[1ex]


 % second row: calendar
 \calrow{\color{blue}Jangmi} & \calrow{\color{blue}Aru} & \calrow{\color{blue}Vosik} \\
 \calperiod{04} & \calperiod{05} & \calperiod{06} \\[1ex]

 % third row: week day and month
 \calrow{\color{blue}Jakhong} & \calrow{\color{blue}Paipai} & \calrow{\color{blue}Chiti} \\
 \calperiod{07} & \calperiod{08} & \calperiod{09} \\[1ex]


 % forth row: calendar
 \calrow{\color{blue}Phere} & \calrow{\color{blue}Phaikuni} & \calrow{\color{blue}Matijong} \\
 \calperiod{10} & \calperiod{11} & \calperiod{12} \\
 };

 \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In section 45 of the PGF manual you'll find your answers. The interesting line in your code is the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every calendar/.style={week list}]
```

You could add some style options there. For example concerning day spacing as `day xshift` and `day yshift` (set to 1pt for the following picture).

[image: small calendar]

Or maybe you want to adjust the shifting between months. Use `month xshift` and `month yshift` (xshift 10em for the following picture).

[image: xshift]

Just mess around with it

Comment: Thanking you , I need some help from you how do i print single month in one page, so that i will get 12 pages for 12 months @TeXnician